# Adding Storybook knobs in React Hooks app with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, storybook

I have an app using React hooks, and I am also using there Storybook. 
After adding Redux I have a small problem.
While adding Provider as global decorator helped me load the initial state for my components and display them in Storybook, now that everythign is in store, I cannot figure out how to add knobs to be able to display my components with different state.

Here's the config file with Provider

```
const store = createStore(reducer);  
addDecorator(Story => (<div
style={style}>
<Provider store={store}>
<Story />
</Provider>   </div> ));
```

And here's one of the stories which worked fine before Redux (with useSelector and useDispatch hooks) was added

```
const stories = storiesOf('UI Components', module)
stories.addDecorator(withKnobs)
stories.add('Input Button', () => {
const groupId = 'Props'
const statusesKnob = select('Button states', appStates, Object.values(appStates)[0], groupId)
  return <InputButton getAppState={statusesKnob} />
})
```

States

```
const appStates = [
  LOADING: 'LOADING',
  INACTIVE: 'INACTIVE',
  ERROR:'ERROR',
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I finally added the store to the a global variable and used store.dispatch

if decorator.js:
    window.REDUX_STORE = store;

in the story:
    window.REDUX_STORE.dispatch(...);

Comment: I went different way. I moved the state logic to a separate wrapping component. This way, the UI component is getting state changes not directly, but as props from the wrapping component. And it's easy to use such a UI-only component in Storybook.